# What is a regular expression to identify the AWS basic auth value in the repository for git-secret?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, github, git-secret

I want to identify the AWS basic auth from the files in a repository. For this I want to add a pattern for git-secret to scan the value for basic auth value in the repository.

I have tried with the below pattern:

```
git secrets --add '^\bBasic [A-Za-z0-9[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>=]{60}$'

patterns =  (\"|')?(Basic )[A-Za-z0-9\\+=]{60}(\"|')$
```

The script is as follows:

```sh
git secrets --add '^\bBasic [A-Za-z0-9[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>=]{60}$'
git secrets --add 'Basic [A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>=]{60}'
```

I expect the pattern to add for git-secret to identify the AWS basic auth value from the repository.

Here is an example of a basic auth value:

```sh
Basic aW5mQExampleauthvalueGlCeGUzeXk4UmMyT29HeFJOVFVEXAMPLEKEYS==
```

'Basic' +  + <60 characters> then we should flag it.  If it has less than 60, or more than 60, then it's not a valid string.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern worked fine for me, you just missed one thing:

```
^(\"|')?Basic [A-Za-z0-9\\+=]{60}(\"|')?$
```

You forgot the last "?" for the second optional single or double quote.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this pattern work only for some scenario, if the string is below format it will not identify
{"value" : "Basic aW5mQExampleauthvalueGlCeGUzeXk4UmMyT29HeFJOVFVEXAMPLEKEYS=="}

Comment: If you have other characters before or after the key, you must either: take them into account in your regex, or remove "^ ... $"

Answer (score 0):

> for `git-secret`

Actually, that regex, as proposed by [Npok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11534753/npok)'s [answer](http://for%20git-secret?), won't need [`git-secret`](https://git-secret.io/) much longer.

(Plus: [Secret scanning’s push protection is available on public repositories, for free](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-05-09-secret-scannings-push-protection-is-available-on-public-repositories-for-free) (May. 2023))

As of June 2021:

> ### [Secret scanning now supports user defined patterns on private repositories](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-06-04-secret-scanning-now-supports-user-defined-patterns-on-private-repositories/):
>
> **GitHub Advanced Security customers can now specify custom patterns for use in private repo secret scanning**.
>
> [image: secret scanning -- https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/secret-scanning-create-custom-pattern.png]
>
> When a new pattern is specified, secret scanning searches a repository's entire git history for it, as well as any new commits.
>
> [User defined patterns are in](https://github.com/github/roadmap/projects/1#card-54656341) beta on cloud and will be available on [GHES next quarter](https://github.com/github/roadmap/projects/1#card-54656355).
> They can be defined at the repository and organization level.

See:

- "[Defining custom patterns for secret scanning](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-security/defining-custom-patterns-for-secret-scanning)"
- "[About secret scanning](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-security/about-secret-scanning)"

---

And:

> ### [Secret scanning now push protects custom patterns](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-12-15-secret-scanning-now-push-protects-custom-patterns) (Dec. 2022)
>
> Previously, GitHub Advanced Security customers could enable push protection for all [patterns supported by default](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/code-security/secret-scanning/secret-scanning-patterns#supported-secrets-for-push-protection).
>
> Now, admins can also enable [push protection for any custom pattern](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/code-security/secret-scanning/defining-custom-patterns-for-secret-scanning) defined at the repository or organization level.
> Push protection for enterprise-level custom patterns will come in January.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/81782111/207498360-10037928-bd7b-4379-83db-16e234db4880.png?w=960&ssl=1 -- blocked custom pattern]
>
> - [Read our blog post to learn how you can push protect your custom patterns](https://github.blog/2022-12-15-github-advanced-security-customers-can-now-push-protect-their-custom-patterns)
> - [Learn how to secure your repositories with secret scanning](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/code-security/secret-scanning/about-secret-scanning)